# Arrays & Loops, Sentinel Won't Work (C Prog)

Tags: c, arrays, constants, defined

**I am having trouble getting (-999) to work in this code. I had it as an if/break statement as well as in a while statement but it doesn't seem register it. Help please!**

---

Write a simple program (to demonstrate use of array) that asks a user to type in numbers and
keep typing in numbers until one of two things happen:

The user enters -999

The total number of numbers entered reaches 5

You program will stop asking for new input based on either condition above. Once one of the above conditions are met, the program will output all numbers entered.

---

See code below:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
#define QUANT 5
{
int number [QUANT], i = 0;

while (i < QUANT) {
    for (i = 0; i < QUANT; i++)
        scanf("%i", &number[i]);
    if (number[i] == -999) {
        break;
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < QUANT; i++)
printf("Element %i: %i \n", i, number[i]);

}
```

Comment: Another thing you need to fix:  assume the user enters `1, 7, -999`, you are still printing all 5 values in the array, even though you should only print 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the `while` loop, and put the `break` statement inside the `for` loop.

```
#define QUANT 5
int main()
{
    int number [QUANT], i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < QUANT; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &number[i]);
        if (number[i] == -999)
            break;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("Element %i: %i \n", j, number[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

You might have noticed even as you wrote the program that you were including two comparisons `i < QUANT`, which is a little bit strange.  In any case, the `break` statement only breaks out of the `while` loop after the `for` loop had completed looping.

I've also changed the final loop to use another variable `j` that it compares with the `i` set during the previous loop.  This causes the program not to output uninitialized values, in the event that the user does type in `-999`.